# python-telegram-bot replying to specific user in group chat

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am working on a telegram  bot project for local people in my area, I would like to know is it possible for bot to reply back to same user that send the command in group chat, but not have the rest of the group see it. I thought I saw this as a possibility, but I cannot find it on python-telegram-bot github.

I am not looking for a copy/pastable code, I just need help in the right direction, I haven't received any responses in the telegram group chat on the matter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried taking the sender's chat ID (if you get it) and send a message to the chat with this ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some options

1. **Reply in private chat**
   Send a message directly to the users id. The problem is, the user have to unlock you before, by sending your bot `/start`. This may be practical for small groups.
2. **Guide the user to a private chat**
   Send a link like `t.me/your_bot?start=XXXX`. The user starts your bot in a private chat and sends the parameter (`XXXX`). Then you can evalute if its the right keyword and user and then send your message. Even more elegant is to use a [InlineKeyBoardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) with this url.
3. **Use a button with an alert**
   Reply with an InlineKeyBoardButton and use [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) with `show_alert=True` to show a text when the right user clicks it like [@nnbbot](https://t.me/nnbbot) does it. The drawback of this method is, you can only use up to 200 charachters.